# How to handle invalid data rows for multiple enums using custom exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I need to handle invalid data rows when importing and parsing a csv file in Java.
In case my program does not accommodate a specific value (e.g.  professor as a Profession)
a InvalidCharacteristicException should be thrown. My program should handle such exceptions by issuing a warning statement and show the line number in the config file where the error was found.But I do not know how to get the total lines of my csv file, and handle exceptions for multiple enum type data. Also, I am not quite sure how to grab the exact line where an error occurred.

Here are enum Profession and enum BodyType for example.

```
public enum Profession {
DOCTOR, CEO, CRIMINAL, HOMELESS, UNEMPLOYED , UNKNOWN, NONE;
}

public enum BodyType {
SLIM, OBESE, ATHLETIC, UNSPECIFIED; 
}
```

Here is what the csv looks like.

```
  [0],    [1], [2],    [3]  ,    [4]    ,   [5]   ,  [6] ,   [7]  ,  [8] , [9]
class, gender, age, bodyType, profession, pregnant, isYou ,species, isPet, role
scenario:green,   ,         ,           ,         ,        ,      ,      ,
person, female, 24, average ,           , FALSE   ,        ,      ,      , passenger
animal, male  ,  4,         ,           , FALSE   ,        , dog  , TRUE , pedestrian
.
.
```

Here is what I am thinking and what I've tried. 
Here is my custom exception.

```
public class InvalidCharacteristicException extends Exception
{   
    public InvalidCharacteristicException() 
    {       
        super("WARNING: invalid characteristic in config file in line" + 
             + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber());
    }
}
```

Below is part of my readCsv() method and what I am thinking.

```
File file = new File(csvFile); 
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);   
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = "";
String[] tempArr;

for (total rows of the csv file)
{
    if (tempArr[3] is not BodyType.valueOf())
    {

        throw new InvalidCharacteristicException();
    }
    if (tempArr[4] is not Profession.valueOf())
    {
        throw new InvalidCharacteristicException();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that [StackTraceElement#getLineNumber](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#getLineNumber()) returns the line number in your *code* that throws `InvalidCharacteristicException` (specifically called the source line in the documentation), instead of the line number in the *config* it was thrown for. We can solve this by changing `InvalidCharacteristicException` as follows:

```
class InvalidCharacteristicException extends Exception {
    public InvalidCharacteristicException(int configLineNum) {
        super("WARNING: invalid characteristic in config file in line " + configLineNum);
    }
}
```

Now that we are passing in the config line number, we somehow need to keep track of it in the `for`. You don't show the exact `for` you're using, but assuming you can keep track of a variable called `configLineNum` (for example, you could explicitly increment `configLineNum` by 1 every time you process a line), you would then use

```
throw new InvalidCharacteristicException(configLineNum);
```

wherever you need to throw the exception.